# Error using log10() for floating point number -2.584877722073e-33

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision, logarithm

I've encountered a strange error trying to work with a floating point number. I'm attempting to calculate the log10 (in "math.h") of the following number:

```
-0.000000000000000000000000000000002584877722073    ==    -2.584877722073e-33
```

It keeps crashing. Is this a valid float? Granted I am dealing with manipulating the raw data of the float itself.

I have researched floats, and from my understanding this is not NaN, Inf, or a Denormal number. The binary doesn't seem to match anything invalid:

```
1 | 00010010 | 10101101011111001000100
```

Are there restrictions to numbers with this precision? What might be causing the issue?

Comment: Even `double` doesn't give you precision that good. :P

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun: `double` gives you up to 17 decimal digits of precision...

Comment: @JoeZ Oh wait. Nevermind. I just realized it's the _significant_ digits that count. Rather embarrassing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compute the logarithm of a negative number and expect a real result.  You should be getting a domain error.